# Reflection of two electromagnetic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

Can Electromagnetic waves be reflected by another electromagnetic wave without having any physical (transparent or opaque) material (i.e., in free space with one wave having twice the amplitude of the other)?

Comment: So you mean just two waves colliding in free space & reflecting off each other?

Comment: Yes. Like two em waves moving in opposite direction but having amplitude ratio of 2. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 5):

No, different EM waves do (classically) not interact, they just pass through each other. There are (tiny) contributions to a photon-photon diagram in quantum electrodynamics which could be seen as photons scattering off each other, but, at the macroscopic level where we usually talk about EM waves, there isn't any interaction at all.

Comment: Here's a fun question.  What about near a magnetar?  If the EM waves have large enough amplitudes, they could cause pair production.  Would that influence reflection?  (Note:  This is mostly a fun imaginative question that I have not thought of before, so do not take it too seriously.)

Comment: @honeste_vivere: I think that pair production has nothing to do with large EM fields, since the energy of the individual photons does *not* increase, and these are the objects participating in the pair production process. A "box diagram" between four photons with a fermion loop (the "box") inside is the (tiny) QED correction I allude to. Pair production usually only happens for high energy photons (gamma rays) in the presence of a nucleus, since "photon -> pair" is kinematically forbidden.

Comment: Oh, sorry for being careless with my terminology.  I guess I was curious about magnetars because I often see references to pair production from the vacuum near these objects.  Quantum has always plagued me, as I cannot get an intuitive grasp of most of the concepts.  Wait, why is photon to pair kinematically forbidden?

Comment: @honeste_vivere: Energy and momentum conservation cannot simultaneously hold for a photon "decaying" into a pair - if you try to impose both, you will run into a contradiction, hence the process is forbidden. || Some people like to talk about the contribution to vacuum energy coming from Feynman diagrams that look like (short-time) pair production as pairs actually emerging from the vacuum and then annihilating again (also, they like to explain Hawking radiation with it). I, however, am not convinced this is a suitable interpretation of the quantum field theory results.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thanks for the clarification.  I did not realize the idea of pair production from a vacuum was a controversial idea.  That's kind of fun…